# Forcing a square to fit in a grid

Tags: java

The method is supposed to draw a square on a 10x10 grid using the length and x,y coordinate an user inputs and adjust the length in case the square doesn't fit.
I'm having trouble figuring out the math for adjusting the length to fit the grid.

For example, if the user inputs (x-7, y-2, length-4) my square goes out of the grid by 1.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk5lB.png)

```
public static void drawSquare(int x, int y, int len) {
        if(x+len>10)
            len = Math.max(x, len)-Math.min(x, len);
        if(y+len>10)
            len = Math.max(y, len)-Math.min(y, len);
        System.out.println("side length = " + len + ", area = " + len*len);
        drawLine(x, y, x+len, y);
        drawLine(x+len,y,x+len,y-len);
        drawLine(x+len, y-len, x, y-len);
        drawLine(x, y-len, x, y);
    }
```

Comment: You'll want to call `Math.min( x + len, 10)` for example, to take whichever is less: the sum of the x coordinate and the length, or the maximum coordinate(10). Same pattern for the y+len; and use Math.max for the subtraction cases.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas so like this? `len = Math.max(x, len)-Math.min( x + len, 10);;`

Comment: You need to track lenX and lenY separately. If the origin is (7,3) and you draw a square with width 4, it should draw a rectangle 3 wide and 4 tall.

Comment: My first comment was in relation to the drawLine statements. You can remove entirely the first two if statement and instead replace every part of drawLine calls that have +/- len with appropriate min/max calls.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Just think about how the drawsquare method should call another method drawLine. Think about how to find each point in a square using the two coordinates and the given length of the square, also using if statements to make sure it fits the graph

```
public class unit3frq {
    public void drawSquare(int x, int y, int len) {
        // first check whether it fits on the grid
        int xsum = x + len; int ydiff = y - len;
        if (xsum > 10) xsum = 10 - x; if (ydiff < 0) ydiff = 0 - y;
        if ((x - xsum) > (y - ydiff)) xsum = ydiff+x-y;
        else ydiff = xsum+y-x;
          
        drawLine(x, y, x, ydiff); // go down
        drawLine(x, y, xsum, y); // go right
        drawLine(x, ydiff, xsum, ydiff); // down then right
        drawLine(xsum, y, xsum, ydiff); // right then down
          
        int side = xsum - x;
        System.out.println("side length = " + side + ", area = " + Math.pow(side, 2));
        }

    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        int xdiff = x2 - x1; int ydiff = y2 - y1;
        if (xdiff < 0) xdiff = 0 - xdiff; if (ydiff < 0) ydiff = 0 - ydiff;
        if (xdiff > ydiff) {
            int x = x1; int y = y1;
            while (x <= x2) {
                System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                x++;
                if (ydiff != 0) y += ydiff / xdiff;
            }
        } else {
            int x = x1; int y = y1;
            while (y <= y2) {
                System.out.println("(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
                y++;
                if (xdiff != 0) x += xdiff / ydiff;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        unit3frq u3 = new unit3frq();
        u3.drawSquare(0, 0, 10);

    }
     
}
```